# VKsdk Android Studio получить id пользователя, под которым зашел

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, sdk, android-vksdk

Нужно получить id пользователя под которым зашел в приложение, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Довольно просто:

Хранится он здесь: `VKAccessToken.currentToken().userId;`

Вот так его можно безопасно узнать:

```
int getMyId() { 
    final VKAccessToken vkAccessToken = VKAccessToken.currentToken(); 
    return vkAccessToken != null ? Integer.parseInt(vkAccessToken.userId) : 0; 
}
```